# static linking of libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

At the moment I am a beginner with C++. I am writing my programs in linux (chakra linux) and I have the following problem:

I need to use some features of C++11 so I compile as `c++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` and it works fine in my laptop. Then I take the `a.out` file and upload it into my university cluster and I try to run it but I get the message

```
./a.out: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by ./a.out)
./a.out: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.13' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

looking on the internet it seems that a work around is to compile in my laptop as

```
c++ -std=c++11  test.cpp -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

and then try to run the code in the cluster. I did try that and got the message

```
./a.out: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

I also tried to compile in the cluster, but it does not work, I think that it has to do with the fact that the cluster compiler are gcc 4.3.2 or intel icpc (ICC) 13.1.1

I would like to know if there is any way around this problem or if I am doing something wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you compiling on a 64-bit machine but the remote machine is 32-bit? (Try adding `-m32` when compiling)

Comment: Just static link **everything** with `-static`. You will get a large/enormous binary, but it won't require any external libraries.

Comment: Although, the errors seems to come from the libc, have you tried to compile using `-static`, thereby linking all libs static?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, the -static flag was usefull